# Strange signs and symbols in my sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

i have 2 strange things i have noticed when using my sharepoint list:
Could anyone tell me what these signs and symbols are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first sign, I am not sure but looks like something broken (is this Title column?). 2nd sign will be shown on "multiple lines of text" fields when content length is larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured the list form using JSON?

The first signs may be related to the JSON code you set

[image]

When the content length is large, the second symbol will be displayed in the "**Multiple lines of text**" field. **The second symbol means See more**.

[image]

Here is **[an article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)** on how to configure the list form